# Substituição de JavaScript If else com boolean

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dúvida em um código de JavaScript.
Estou tentando fazer um código de comparação, porém quero retirar as palavras "true" e "false" e substituir por outras palavra que posso colocar.
Estou usando If else mas será que isso ajuda?

JavaScript Comparison

```
<p> x = 5; y =5 => x == y 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = 5;
        var y = 5;
        document.write(x == y);

        if (x == y) {
            document.write("palavra aleatória");
        } else {
            document.write("palavra aleatória2");
        }
    </script>
</p>
```

Obrigado pessoal!

Comment: A tua pergunta não está muito clara. Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer e dar um exemplo?

Comment: Se queres retirar as palavras true ou false retire document.write(x == y);

Comment: Usando o setter talvez você consiga: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score -1):

Se vai ajudar ou não depende do contexto em que esse javascript for aplicado pois as instruções condicionais são usadas ​​para executar ações diferentes com base em diferentes condições.

A instrução  **if** é usada para especificar um bloco de código JavaScript a ser executado se a condição for verdadeira.

A instrução  **else** é usada para especificar um bloco de código JavaScript a ser executado se a condição for falsa.

Use a instrução **else if**  para especificar uma nova condição, se a primeira condição for falsa.

Exemplo if else

```
if(x==y) {
    document.write("palavra aleatória");;
} else {
    document.write("palavra aleatória2");
}
```

ou usando a notação ternária

```
    var resultado = (x == y) ? document.write('palavra aleatória') : document.write('palavra aleatória2');
```

Exemplo if - else if - else

```
 if(x< y) {
    document.write("palavra aleatória");;
} else if(x == y) {
    document.write("palavra aleatória2");
} else {
    document.write("palavra aleatória3");
}
```

Muitas vezes, na programação, você vai precisar de um tipo de dados que só pode ter um de dois valores, como

- SIM NÃO
- LIGADO DESLIGADO
- VERDADEIRO FALSO (true false)

Nesse caso você pode usar a função booleana para descobrir se uma expressão (ou uma variável) é verdadeira:

`document.write(5 == 5);`

Nota: Letras maiúsculas nas instruções (If, IF, Else etccc) gera um erro de JavaScript.